How to create a cost center for a GitHub organization using API?
I'm trying to figure out how to create a cost center for an Organization in GitHub, using its API.
I looked all over the documentation and only found how to list cost centers (using Rest API):
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/enterprises/companyname/settings/billing/cost-centers

and I'm getting response like this:
    "costCenters": [
            {
                "id": "e6c14655-71eb-472a-b1db-0000000",
                "name": "some-name",
                "resources": [
                    {
                        "type": "Org",
                        "name": "full-name-here"
                    }
                ]
            },

Also looked into the GraphQL API and mutations especially and don't see how to create a cost center..
Tried to look for something in GraphQL explorer but also nothing.

Is it possible to create a cost center using GitHub API? I need to automate creating them (all organizations have to have a cost center assigned and I need to keep them in sync).

It looks like there is neither REST nor GraphQL API to manage cost centres for a GitHub Enterprise. The only other option to automate cost centre creation/management is to use GitHub UI and browser automation tools like Selenium.

Thanks for a reply - also in the GH documentation there's only one way to create cost centers - which is by the UI: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/billing/using-the-enhanced-billing-platform-for-enterprises/charging-business-units#creating-a-cost-center
